# Bagels (based on big book of python) in c++

Tags: c++, beginner, number-guessing-game

I just learned programming and decided to copy projects in big book of python but in c++ and completed the first project. I would like to know your opinions and how can it be improved! Thanks in advance.

```
int getSecretNumber();
void getClues(int n, int m);
bool gameLoop{true};
int secretNum {getSecretNumber()};

int main()
{
    while (gameLoop == true)
    {
        int guessesCount {1};
        
        std::cout << "\nI am thinking of a 3-digit number. Try to guess what it is." << std::endl;
        std::cout <<"Here are some clues:\n" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "When I say: Pico" << std::endl;
        std::cout <<"That means: One digit is correct but in the wrong position. \n" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "When I say: Fermi" << std::endl;
        std::cout <<"That means: One digit is correct and in the right position. \n" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "When I say: Bagels" << std::endl;
        std::cout <<"That means: No digit is correct. \n" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "I have thought up a number.\nYou have 10 guesses to get it."<< std::endl;

        for (guessesCount; guessesCount < 11; guessesCount++)
        {
            int guess {};
            std::cout << "\nGuess #" << guessesCount << std::endl;
            std::cin >> guess;

            while (guess >1000 || guess <99)
            {
                std::cout << "Please enter a 3-digit number: ";
                std::cin >> guess;
            }

            if (guess == secretNum)
            {
                    std::cout << "You got it!\n" << std::endl;
                    break;
                    
            }else
            {
                getClues(guess, secretNum);
            }

            if(guessesCount == 10){
                std::cout << "\nOut of guess!!\nThe secret number is \n" << secretNum << std::endl;    
            }

        }
        std::cout<<"Do you want to play again? (yes or no): ";
        string playing;
        std::cin >>  playing;

        while(playing != "yes" || playing != "no"){
            std::cout << "Invalid command" << std :: endl;
            std::cout<<"Do you want to play again? (yes or no): ";
            std::cin >> playing;

            if (playing == "no")
            {
                std::cout << "Thanks for playing!"<< std::endl; 
                gameLoop = false;
                break;
            }else if (playing == "yes")
            {
                main();
            }
            
        }
    }
}

int getSecretNumber(){
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    int result = 100 + (rand()%208);
    return result;
}


void getClues(int n, int m)
{
    int n1,n2,n3, m1, m2, m3;

    n1 = n/100;
    n2 = n%100/10;
    n3 = n%10;
    int guessArray[3]{n1,n2,n3};

    m1 = m/100;
    m2 = m%100/10;
    m3 = m%10;
    int secretNumArray[3]{m1,m2,m3};

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (guessArray[i] == secretNumArray[i])
        {
            std::cout << "fermi ";
        }else if(guessArray[i] == secretNumArray[0] || guessArray[i] == secretNumArray[1] || guessArray[i] == secretNumArray[2]){
            // idk how to find if contain in the array...
            std::cout << "pico ";
        }else{
            std::cout << "bagels ";
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you posted this! As the code stands there is both algorithmic complexity in the game logic, and complexity involved with transforming your code into clean C++ code. If it were me, I'd focus only on the latter right now. In particular, you might consider editing the code to make it into a trivial game where the number to be guessed is only 1 digit: Then there will be no algorithmic complexity... and the answers you get here will be "100% C++ focused". Then you can use what you learned to clean up the full game, and post a separate question w/ the full game. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations on learning to program C++ and writing a nice little game!

## Avoid hardcoding the number of digits

Your program is [hardcoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) to work with numbers of 3 digits. This has lead to some design decisions that a more seasoned developer would see as problematic. For example, in `getClues()` you need to get the individual digits of the guessed and secret numbers, and you do this "by hand". You put the digits in arrays so you can use a `for`-loop, but the first `else`-statement inside the `for`-loop compares the guessed digit against each of the three secret digits manually again.

Consider that after playing for a while, you get so good at it that 3 digits is no longer a challenge, and now you want the program to do numbers of 4 digits. You have to change quite a number of lines to make that happen. Ideally though, you would write your program such that you have this line near the top:

```
constexpr int nDigits = 3;
```

And have all other code derive correctly what to do from this constant, so that when you want 4 digits, you just have to change this single line. For example, to check if the guessed number has exactly 3 digits:

```
while (guess >= std::pow(10, nDigits) || guess < std::pow(10, nDigits - 1))
```

And in `getClues()` you can write:

```
int guessDigits[nDigits];
for (auto& digit: guessDigits)
{
    digit = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
}
```

With the above, the number is still hardcoded in the sense that it is fixed after compiling the code. You could also consider turning it into a non-constant variable, and have the player input the difficulty at the start of the program.

Whenever you have constants, give them a name and declare them somewhere the rest of the code can use it. Another hardcoded number I see is the number of guesses a player gets.

## Make use of the C++ standard library

C++ comes with an extensive [standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) that provides many helpful tools, not just `std::cout`. For example, there are [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) that can store data for you in various ways, and [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) that work on those containers. Instead of using a plain array, consider using [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), and then you can use [`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) or [`std::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) to check if a given value exists in that array:

```
std::array<int, nDigits> guessDigits;
std::array<int, nDigits> secretDigits;
...
for (int i = 0; i < nDigits; ++i)
{
    if (guessDigits[i] == secretDigits[i])
    {
        std::cout << "fermi ";
    } else if (std::count(secretDigits.begin(), secretDigits.end(), guessDigits[i]) > 0) {
        std::cout << "pico ";
    } else {
        std::cout << bagels ";
    }
}
```

`std::array` works if the size is known at compile-time. If you want to make `ndigits` variable, then you woudl have to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) here instead.

## Don't call `main()`

Once you finish the game, you ask if the player wants to go again, and if so you call `main()`. However, recursively calling `main()` is not a very good practice; it could cause more and more stack space being used, and now you have to think about what happens if the player finally decides they don't want to play anymore: how will all these built up calls to `main()` be unraveled?

You also don't need to call `main()`, you can just `break` instead; this will exit the inner `while`-loop, and then the outer `while`-loop will still loop around, which does exactly what you want.

## Use C++'s random number generating functions

You are using C functions to generate random numbers, but there are [C++ ways](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) to do that, which are better in many ways, although you might get used to them. Here is how you can do it:

```
int getSecretNumber() {
    static std::random_device device;
    static std::default_random_engine engine(device());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(std::pow(10, nDigits - 1), std::pow(10, nDigits) - 1);
    return distribution(engine);
}
```

The `std::random_device` will be used as a seed for the random number generator `std::default_random_engine`, and the `std::uniform_int_distribution` is there to use the random number generator to get a fair and unbiased number inside the desired range.

## Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`

[Prefer to use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n); the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually unnecessary and might negatively impact performance.

## Split up the code into more functions

Your `main()` function is quite long, and has several loops nested inside each other. It often helps splitting up your code into more functions in such a case, as this will improve readability and maintainability. A good way to do this is by writing your `main()` function in a very high level way:

```
int main() {
    showInstructions();

    do {
        runSingleGame();
    } while (askToPlayAgain());
}
```

Then start implementing those functions. For example, `showInstructions()` shows you how the game works. I've moved it outside the loop, since I assume that once you played it, you don't need the instructions a second time. But now it's easy to change it, it's just moving a single line.

`runSingleGame()` does everything needed for a single game. This function could look like:

```
void runSingleGame() {
    int secretNum = getSecretNumber();

    std::cout << "I have thought up a number.\n"
                 "You have 10 guesses to get it.\n";

    for (int guessCount = 1; guessCount <= nGuesses; ++guessCount) {
        int guess = askGuess(guessCount);

        if (guess == secretNum) {
            std::cout << "You got it!\n";
            return;
        } else {
            getClues(guess, secretNum);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Out of guesses!\n"
                 "The secret number is: " << secertNum << '\n';
}
```

Notice how `secretNum` can just be a local variable here. There is only a single `for`-loop. Asking for a number and checking if it is valid is a bit complicated, so we move that into its own function as well. Also note how we can now `return` early if the number has been guessed; this avoids having to have an additional `if (guessCount == nGuesses)` to see if you are out of guesses.

Also create functions when you notice that you are repeating more or less the same code multiple times, like when you have to create `guessArray` and `secretNumArray`. Consider making a function that takes an `int` as input, and returns a `std::array` or `std::vector` containing the digits. The `getClues()` would start like this:

```
void getClues(int guess, int secret)
{
    auto guessDigits = intToDigits(guess);
    auto secretDigits = intToDigits(secret);
    ...
}
```